# Send data from controller to view in Laravel using jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel, controller

Hi I can pass the data to Controller and tried to get processed data or array in controller to my view file using jQuery. I tried a lot to figure it out but not getting the data, error shows in console :

**{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Trying to get property of non-object ..."}}**

My stuffs are given below -

Controller :

```
public function addRow()
{
    if(Request::ajax()){
        $row = Input::all();        
    }
    return View::make('add-stock')
        ->with('rows', $row);
}
```

View:

```
@if( isset($rows) )
    @foreach($rows as $row)
    {{$row->row}}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Just a note, $rows will always be set when you use `->with('rows')` (even when it's empty). You may get better results checking for `@if( !empty($rows) )` in your view.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is no `row` property on your `row` object.

```
@if( isset($rows) )
    @foreach($rows as $row)

    // This is where your error is coming from
    {{$row->row}}

    @endforeach
@endif
```

Try leaving off the accessor, like this:

```
@if( isset($rows) )
    @foreach($rows as $row)

    {{ $row }}

    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Yes now error has removed in console , but I can't show it on view page @Ben Harold

Comment: You can't show what? What parameters are you passing to the script in your query string?

Comment: {{ $row }} is not appearing on view. how to show. actually i want to run loop with this $row value in php script

Comment: What is the output if you `dd($row);` right before you `return View::make()` in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Request::all() / Input::all() returns an array, not an object. And you are trying to access an array like an object. Use []

Comment: try using dd to get a dump of the data